# TableSorter too many records

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, pagination, tablesorter

I have already implemented `TableSorter` in my project. Now the problem is that in some case I need many records more than thousand. And `TableSorter` plugin does pagination client side through ajax. I want it to do server-side pagination + I want to sort on a single page, not on whole data. i.e. If there are 10 records on a single page of `TableSorter`, sorting must be done on that single Page(on that 10 records only).  I can't change to another table plugin. What should I do? My data is coming from model.

Comment: tablesorter transform grid from html table. To do serser side pagination you create grid dynamicly, not transform. So you can not do  server side pagination with tablesorter. you should use another plug-in.

Comment: If you want to use another plug-in, I will share a mvc example.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi, thanks for your reply but I can't change the plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the [pager ajax demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html), I had to change the `serverSideSorting` option manually to make it sort the current table contents. Maybe that will also work for you? Try including this code:

```
$('table').bind('pagerInitialized', function(e, c){
    // allow current content sorting; this variable is automatically
    // set to true when ajax is initialized
    this.config.serverSideSorting = false;
});
```